# How to take an engineered approach to making a website?

Tags: php

I'm thinking of starting a website (Not static but PHP based) - something like a portal.

However, i want to do this right. Can anyone help me in delineating the various processes that my site can go through ?

Like :

- How the data flows between different pages (data flow diagram) ?
- Steps in selecting a design
- etc.. etc...

Basically i'm looking for some well defined practices in the software engineering industry which can be followed so that my website will be on the right track. I have studied Software engineering (Pressman) however i cannot understand how the techniques given can be applied for web projects.

Is there any book which i can refer to for a better understanding of engineering web projects ?

Thanks alot for any help in advance. Would really like some guidance on this.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site - which is a collection of things to know before you go about building a public web site. It's not so much a set of engineering principles, but is very helpful reading.

Answer (score 2):

MVC is one approach that might be worth looking into.

Comment: Yes, i have looked into using CakePHP or CodeIgniter. However, i am not asking about the project intricacies but how a holistic view of each process has to be handled.

Comment: MVC is a pattern or paradigm, not to be confused with specific implementations in php .Net, etc.  If I'm understanding your request, try doing a little research on MVC (the pattern).  I thinkit'll provide answers to many of your above questions.